# How to make all <a> has the same target="_self"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, anchor

How can I make all `<a>` link has the same target of "_self" through jQuery or javascript?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Put this in the `<head>`:

```
<base target="_self">
```

No need for JavaScript - HTML has the feature built in!

Comment: Well, that's an interesting approach. Would this override any target's currently set?

Comment: It sets the default.  Explicit `target` attributes will override it.

Comment: Thanks RichieHindle. I added a note about that to my answer.

Comment: I don't get it. Doesn't that have exactly the same effect as the default for `a` elements anyway? i.e. = `current` in the table at http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/browsers.html#valid-browsing-context-name-or-keyword

Comment: Some user likes to set it so that each link by default will be opened in a new page. So having this will prevent such action.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('a[href]').attr('target','_self');
```

Note: This will override all `ANCHOR` tag's `target` attribute on the page. RichieHindle's answer would be best if you just want to add them where they aren't declared.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('a').attr('target', '_self');
```

Comment: @JaredFarrish's answer while nearly identical, is a bit more accurate as it will only target `<a />` tags which are actually links.